# What is the equivalent of string temp = ""; in C?

Tags: c++, c

I have a string in C++ called temp and currently curious how that string could be represented in C. Unsure if it would constitute being a pointer or using an array.

```
string temp = "";    //c++ code

char * temp;    //c code
```

Comment: A pointer *points* to something, which may or may not be an array. At its core, you're going to have to use an array to represent a string of characters. Whether or not you refer to that with a `char*` or a `char[N]` depends on whether or not the size of the string is known at compile time.

Comment: It kind of depends on how much of the actual `std::string` class you're using. The C-style string literal `""` in is a `const char[1]`, consisting of just a null terminator. You could have a `const char*` in C. If you need to edit it, a `char*`. And then you'll get into all the exciting world of `strcmp` and `strcpy` and so on.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

C doesn't have a native modifiable string class, so there's no simple parallel.

If you want a modifiable buffer, you'll need `char temp[n] = "";` (fixed size, automatic storage) or `char *temp = malloc(n); temp[0] = 0;` (resizable, in heap).

If you have no intention of changing the string, you can use `const char *temp = "";`. (You can still change `temp`, just not the string it points to.)

Comment: Whether an automatic array or mallocated storage is used, the OP should be aware that they also need to initialize the contents to get something that can be interpreted as an empty string (or as anything else).

Comment: @John Bollinger, ug, I meant to include initialization, but it didn't make it in. Fixed.